# Off canvas responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking for a good working example of [off-canvas responsive design](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/offcanvas/technical/). Just trying to replicate the interface of Google+ android application, and add the panel on the right.

Something like [this example](http://www.vinceallen.com/offcanvas/). However this example has a number of issues:

- does not work well on touch screen (Chrome on Galaxy Nexus);
- the menu should be under the content div, not sliding with it;
- the 'menu' button does not slide with the content div to the right.

Can you tell me how it is better to build somethig like this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are looking to make a responsive web application that works with touch devices you should look into jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch. http://jquerymobile.com/ ... http://www.sencha.com/products/touch ... If you don't like any of there stuff maybe build your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zurb Foundation framework includes off-canvas responsive design along w/ a few cool examples and instructions

http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts